# Import/Export mlr task to file?

Tags: mlr

I'd like to export an object of class `Task` into a file, along with the task data associated to it. Is this possible in mlr?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the usual `save`/`load`?

Comment: I tried `saveRDS` but I realized that the exported file was too short, so it did not contain the data.

Comment: Works for me. Have you actually verified that you can't load the exported file?

Comment: Sorry, I did this again and now it worked without a problem. I should have done something wrong in the first try. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `saveRDS` works as expected.